# Can array of objects be considered as a collection of objects in Java?

Tags: java, semantics, naming

Oracle site's definition of collection is:

```
A collection — sometimes called a container — is simply an object that groups multiple 
elements into a single unit.
```

I know Java provides `java.util.Collection`. It includes `Set`, `ArrayList`, `Queue`, etc.

**My question is:** Will I be wrong if I refer an array of objects as a collection of objects? (Even though `java.util.Collection` probably didn't include array)

---

**Edit:**
Something interesting I found. This is how Microsoft defines **arrays** & **collections**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/9ct4ey7x(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You will not be wrong, an array is indeed a collection of objects, although like you said it does not implement the Collection interface. That said people usually refer to stuff that implements Collection when they say collection.

Comment: If you write a text where you define the term "collection" as applying to arrays as well, then you can use that term that way. The English language will not stop you.

Comment: So if I am writing myself a document on objects. I can write a topic header call "collection of objects" and array being one of its sub-topic. That is fine?

Comment: It's worth noting that an array can be an array of primitives whereas a `Collection` is a collection of references.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat a question of semantics. The word "collection" in English could mean "more than one", and thus, yes, an array is a collection. However, in Java, you'd usually see it spelled as Collection, with a capital C - i.e., an object that is of a subtype of `java.util.Collection`. For this meaning, you cannot use an array, as arrays in java do not implement this interface.

Comment: So it is actually misleading if I refer an array of objects as a collection of objects when I am not referring to the util.Collection right?

Comment: @user3437460 IMHO, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this is a problem. In the literal sense an array is a 'collection' ([Read](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm)).

But when you dive into Java the meaning of a collection changes from a mere group of objects to a set of mechanisms to manage(store,retrieve,operate etc) the objects and is specified by the prototype `Collection` interface.

So unless you are overriding the interface in Java your array isn't exactly a collection.

Answer (score 2):

An array is an object with a fix count - including 0 - of places for variables of the same type.
Nothing more.
As you want, you can say this is a kind of collection, or list or a sequence.
But all these terms are well known as names, or part of it, of interfaces or classes which are much more than a simple array
So, if you use these names for an array, other people may not understand correctly what you mean.
My recommendation: **An array is just an array, so call it array**

Answer (score 1):

One difference that can help you with this dilemma. `Array` is an object with contiguous but limited memory.While Collection is a set of objects by the virture of which each object has it's different memory address.

`Arrays` are relatively faster in operations as compared to `Collections`.

`Collections` give you a lot of utility methods on top of `Arrays`.